# Can't print quotient with scanf

Tags: c

My objective in this exercise is to create a function names `MultiTwo()` that will multiply two inserted integers by the user and then print the quotient. `MultiTwo` has to be called inside `main()`.

Here's my try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int MultiTwo(int x, int y, int result);

int main() {
    int x, y, result;

    printf("Insert an integer: \n");
    x = scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Insert a second integer: \n");
    y = scanf("%d", &y);
    result = x * y;

    printf("The quotient of the two inserted integers is: %d", result);

    return 0;   
}
```

I insert two integers and the result I always get, despite the integers inserted, is 1.

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying.  Are you using `MultiTwo` and it's failing?  If so, you should show its definition.

Comment: The return value of scanf is the number of items successfully read, not the value of one of the variables read.

Comment: @FredK Good catch: `1 * 1 == 1`

Comment: "Quotient" is the result of a division operation. What you're calculating is the product.

Comment: To complete your assignment, you need to write the body of `MultiTwo()` and call it in `main()`.  Note that you won't be able to use the `result` parameter sensibly.  You either need a pointer argument or (far better) to return the product of the two integers and omit the `result` argument.

Comment: Yes yes, even though i hate pointer at my current skill level :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = scanf("%d", &x);
```

This first reads the value from input and assigns it to the variable x. Then you clobber that value by setting x to the return value of scanf(), which is the number of variables successfully read, in this case it is 1.

Comment: Dont i assign what i type to x with scanf? How do I set x as the return value of scanf? What i try to do with scanf is to type the value of x and then y, after that its just multiplication

Comment: @OvercomeSupreme This is easily Googled.  First Google result of [scanf example](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c7.htm).  Pretty much gives you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i found the solution by deleting x = and y = ... thank you once again! :)

Comment: Yes, but, you still need to check the return value from `scanf` in the real world. As stated, it is the number of items successfully scanned, not the *value* that was scanned.

Comment: @OvercomeSupreme: You need: `if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read an integer\n"); return 1; /* Or exit(EXIT_FAILURE); and #include <stdlib.h> */ }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Isnt making the smaller the code, but with the same level of functionality the better?
Because i tested my code and whenever I type a char instead of an integer the program terminates.

Comment: That isn't the same functionality.  One diagnoses incorrect input; the other ignores it.  That is different.